# Wiring a headset with push-to-talk functionality to a standard TRRS connector

Tags: circuit-design, audio

I have a headset with a push-to-talk (PTT) functionality that uses a "Kenwood" 2 pin connector. [image: Kenwood connector]

I would like to create an adapter so that it can be used with devices that support standard 3.5 mm TRRS connectors, while retaining the PTT functionality.

Wiring the `SPK+` and `SPK-` output is trivial: [image: TRRS wiring]

Directly wiring `MIC+` to the sleeve of the TRRS connector will cause the microphone to always be active. From my testing, the PTT functionality works as follows: if the PTT button is pressed, `MIC-` is connected to GND, otherwise it is not connected to anything. This is a problem, because the TRRS connector uses a shared ground for the audio and microphone signals. How would I go about transmitting `MIC+` only if `MIC-` is connected to ground?

Comment: Just a comment that wiring the speaker is not trivial. You have short-circuited the left and right output channels together.

Comment: I see. I've tested this set-up with my phone, and it seemed to like it. What would be a better way to connect the speaker?

Comment: That would be a separate question, and a likely duplicate, as similar was previously asked maybe yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the headset wiring diagrams seem to use speaker ground for mic ground too, and the PTT wire just connects the PTT pin to the ground.

This is proven by your test because mic always works, it must have the GND and MIC pins already connected.

So the PTT just grounds a pin and the radios use that as digital input and go into transmit mode when PTT pin is grounded.

So what you want that the MIC only works when PTT is pushed is impossible by just wiring an adapter. It would require active electronics and that would require batteries or some other power source.

If you want to change your plan, at least the PTT button can be wired like the phone headsets with a pushbutton to answer calls.